# npm install command gives ERR on each line

Tags: npm, npm-install, react-scripts

I downloaded a npm project which worked just fine on other computers.
I try to run "npm install" and "npm start" commands, but I get "ERR" on each line.
I tried different solutions, like deleting the package-lock file, installing npm with the react-scripts argument, but nothing seems to help.
I get:

`````
loadDep:react-scripts → 3 ▄ ╢███████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine @testing-library/jest-dom@4.2.4: wanted: {"node":">=8","npm":">=6"} (current: {"node":"8.10.npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
loadDep:fsevents → 304    ▐ ╢██████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine fsevents@2.1.2: wanted: {"node":"^8.16.0 || ^10.6.0 || >=11.0.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0"loadDep:semver → resolveW ▌ ╢██████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
npm ERR! Linux 4.19.84-microsoft-standard
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /mnt/c/Projects/myproj-front-end/myproj-front-end/npm-debug.log````
`````

Answer (score 2):

You must be using an old npm... It may be some newer version broke the functionality of the older version.

Try upgrading your npm through **sudo npm install -g npm@version** for a specific version. Then open the new terminal and check for the npm version by **npm -v**.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by installing the latest version of npm and **rebooting my machine** afterwards. The reboot is important, otherwise you will still be using the old version of npm.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
reboot
```

If you are using a non-Unix terminal (windows), simply switch your computer off and on again and omit the `reboot` command.

Comment: saved me from having to find out what the latest version is, thanks!